# Issue with DateTime in Rust with juniper and chrono

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, juniper, rust-chrono

I've got the problem, that I have a graphQL query, with a DateTime and cannot use it with juniper.

At the documentation they write that they have the scalar type feature chrono::DateTime build in by default. So I pub imported the DateTime from chrono. Now I have the Error:

`wrong number of type arguments: expected 1, found 0 expected 1 type argument`

The code:

```
use chrono::DateTime;
pub struct ProjectDate;
pub mod project_date {    
    use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
    #[doc = "An ISO-8601 encoded UTC date string."]
    type DateTime = super::DateTime;
```

I use `juniper = "^0.14.2"` and `chrono = "0.4.0"`

Any idea, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `DateTime` depends on the TimeZone type. You should use `DateTime<Utc>` for example. Or make your type variable: `type DateTime<T>` = super::DateTime<T>;

Comment: The type part is autogenerated, i tried `use chrono::DateTime as DT; use chrono::Utc; pub type DateTime = DT<Utc>;`. But this didn't work either. Now i got this issue: the trait `githubloader::current_projects::_::_serde::Deserialize<'_>` is not implemented for `chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>`

Answer (score 1):

The solution was the `serde` feature at chrono and the `DateTime<Utc>` from @Netwave.

```
chrono = { version = "^0.4.13", features= ["serde"] }
```

and

```
pub type DateTime = chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>;
```